# Rails webpacker has no packs directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, webpacker

*Premable:  as a Rails 6.1.3 application, on deployment, I noticed that migrations were not launched, thus there may be a capistrano issue at hand.*

Being an initial deployment, shared files were copied over, the database manually created, migrated and populated with a postgresql archive.

Launching the server however leads to a complaint
`Webpacker can't find application.js` 
and in examining the directory structure, the `public/packs` directory is absent.
On localhost, these are created on first page call-up; but this is not occuring on a VPS.

Upon consultation of the [Rails guide for webpacker](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html#deploying-webpacker)  neither command
`bundle exec webpacker:compile` nor  `bundle exec assets:precompile` run, both with the same error:

```
bundler: command not found: assets:precompile
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

yet `bundle install` runs successfuly repeatedly, invoking `webpacker 5.4.0`.

`config/webpacker.yml` has

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
```

So this behaviour is contrary to the assertion in the guide "By default, Webpacker compiles automatically on demand in development when a Rails page loads. "

How should this be configured for proper deployment, in both development and production modes?

Comment: Are you ending up with binstubs for `webpacker` on deployment? You might try `bundle install --binstubs`.

Comment: do you mean that the application's release, say `releases/20210707180313`  would have a `bin` directory with files `webpack` and `webpack-dev-serv`?  They are there...  tried the command; no change in behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The error is about missing 'gem executables', which can happen if the binstubs don't get installed for some reason.

Comment: The command to precompile assets is `bundle exec rails assets:precompile`, not `bundle exec assets:precompile` (notice the `rails` command). Also, are you deploying your application in development mode? you should deploy in production mode (and precompile assets during deploy). If you think there might be a capistrano issue, check the capistrano logs too.

Comment: Have you been able to fix it? Same issue here @Jerome

Comment: Sorry @Marcel , I wrestled a long while with it & did find a solution, but quite a few days later... and had other matters impeding me to recall this question.  And now I fail to jog my memory - I (more probably) launched commands directly on the VPS.